# Running php script using cron on a Mac

Tags: php, cron

What is wrong with this cronjob?

```
* * * * * * php -f /Documents/Programs/WeeklyHours/weekly_hour.php
```

I have combed through the various cron questions on StackExchange and nothing is working. When I run php -f /Documents/Programs/WeeklyHours/weekly_hour.php in the terminal it works perfectly. I know the cron jobs are running because I am getting error mail.  At the bottom of the error mail messages it is saying "/bin/sh: Applications: command not found." Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You have one more * than required in your crontab entry

Try

```
0-59 * * * * php -f /Documents/Programs/WeeklyHours/weekly_hour.php
```

The 0-59 is so that it will run every minute

Answer (score 0):

The cron job likely runs under a different user which does not have its `PATH` set up the same as you, so it cannot find the `php` executable. You are able to simply type `php` because your `PATH` variable is set up to include its parent directory; that is not necessarily true for all other users.

Explicitly specify the path to the executable, e.g. `/usr/bin/php`. To figure out which `php` you're using, type:

```
$ which php
```

Comment: which php outputs /usr/local/bin/php. I tried * * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /Documents/Programs/WeeklyHours/weekly_hour.php and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 * * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /Documents/Programs/WeeklyHours/weekly_hour.php >> /ww/xx.log 2>&1
```

You can view the log.